# How to use multiple store in micronfrontend

Tags: javascript, react-redux, state-management, micro-frontend

Problem statement -

The host app consumes lot of MFE from different APPS.
The MFE are served from other app which have their own redux store as they are part of big apps.

When we expose providers from MFE and consumes in host app, we end up having multiple providers for example -

```html
<!-- hostprovider -->
<Provider store={hostStore}>
  <App1Provider></App1Provider> <!-- provider from App1 along with store -->
  <App2Provider></App2Provider> <!-- provider from App2 along with store -->
  <App3Provider></App3Provider> <!-- provider from App3 along with store -->
</Provider
```

It works fine, when only one provider is added and rest are commented, i.e, App1Provider is added. But as soon as Provider from other sub apps is added it throws following exception -

```js
Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

I explore little about context and connect api, but I'm not sure how to use them in microfrontend context.